# unity StartCoroutine() function does not calling function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can some help my why does this code not executing I get the 2 debug messages from the CallRollDice function but nothing from the RollDice function.

```
public void CallRollDice() 
    {
        Debug.Log("clicked");
        StartCoroutine("RollDice");
        Debug.Log("ran");
    }
    private IEnumerable RollDice()
    {
        Debug.Log("called");
        
        int randomInt1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            randomInt1 = Random.Range(0, diceFaces.Length);
            diceImage.sprite = diceFaces[randomInt1];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        }
    }
```

When i researched the topic i found out that StartCoroutine function in some cases requires a function but in my case it is requires a string.

I am using unity version 2021.3.30f1 (lst)

Comment: @OP if additionally you would use the direct call `StartCoroutine(RollDice())` instead of going string/name based the compiler would tell you the issue right away ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) says:

> A coroutine is a method that you declare with an IEnumerator return type and with a yield return statement included somewhere in the body.

So you should change the return type to `IEnumerator`.

```
private IEnumerator RollDice()
```

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable`:

```cs
private IEnumerator RollDice()
```

Although strings can cause a run-time error if you typo in them. So you get the error at compile-time, I recommend:

```
StartCoroutine(RollDice());

// or

IEnumerator coroutine = RollDice();
StartCoroutine(coroutine);
```

Comment: thx for the answer it solved my problem